# Sum of prime generating numbers.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was trying to solve a [project euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problem which goes like :

> Find the sum of all positive integers $n$ not exceeding $100,000,000$
>   such that for every divisor $d$ of $n$, $d+\frac nd$ is prime.

So this is what I did.

if $d + \frac nd$ is prime and $1$ is always a divisor of $n$ thus for $d=1$, this should be true. Thus we'll get $1+n$ should be prime. Meaning $n$ is even.

Now if $n$ is even then $2$ becomes a divisor of $n$. Thus $\left(2+\frac n2\right)$ should also be prime which means $\frac n2$  should be odd and so we get $n$ should not be a multiple of $4$.

So from above what we have is $n+1$ is prime and $n$ is not a multiple of $4$.

I couldn't find any more constraints on $n$.

How do I proceed further?

I have a feeling that these are all the constraints I need on $n$ but I'm not able to prove this.

Edit: As peter in comments suggested $n$ also needs to be square-free. So we have another condition on $n$.

Comment: Promising approach, consider that $n=1$ also satisfies the property.

Comment: Also, $n$ must be squarefree : If $p^2\mid n$, then $p+\frac{n}{p}$ is divisible by $p$ , hence not prime.

Comment: @Peter Yes that's another condition.

Answer (score 1):

The following PARI/GP programs determines the number of positive integers $n$ upto $10^8$ satisfying the condition and the sum of those :

```
? z=0;su=0;forprime(p=2,10^8+1,n=p-1;if(issquarefree(n)==1,gef=1;fordiv(n,d,if(gef==1,if(ispseudoprime(d+n/d)==0,gef=0)));if(gef==1,su=su+n;z=z+1)));print(z,"  ",su)
39627  1739023853137
```

The results for the number of prime factors of $n$ :

- 0 factors : 1/1
- 1 factors : 1/2
- 2 factors : 30301 / 1358128392798
- 3 factors : 9009 / 370999149930
- 4 factors : 312 / 9892176864
- 5 factors : 3 / 4133542

Comment: As the output shows the problem cannot be solved by hand, there are too many numbers satisfying the property.

Comment: not by writing them out ... by calculating number of values of certain types it might be ...

Comment: yeah actually the problems are supposed to be solved by write code but not with the obvious brute force way.

Comment: I don’t wonder if the point is to code up an algorithm that iterates efficiently over the primes, then check the conditions you have established. (Basically what the code above does)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got:

- You only really need to care about divisors below the square root of $n$ because $d_1d_2=n$ implies that $d_1+{n\over d_1}=d_1+d_2=d_2+d_1=d_2+{n\over d_2}$ and the lower is always going to be below the square root. That results in divisors no larger than $10^4$ needing to be checked.
- By similar logic, you can avoid numbers that aren't squarefree. Because, you can split the power over the divisors, leading to both addends having a common factor, which factoring out would find.
- by the product  of squares is a square, you really only need to check for divisibility by prime squares ( basically what a squarefree check is, just thought I'd mention it)
- The properties of being 1 less than a prime, and squareefree means that prime can only be the prime 2; or 3 mod 4.  Not being 1 mod 9 ( the next square) means not being 1 mod 18, which then has only 1 case mod 36 that works due to 1 mod 36 being covered by 1 mod 4, we can also eliminate primes that are 19 mod 36 then.
- we can then eliminate primes that are 51 mod 100 etc.